# Regência de «levar» (=demorar)

Tags: regência-verbal

Quais destas frases estão corretas?

> (1) O João levou três horas a/para terminar o trabalho.
>   (2) Levou ao João três horas a/para terminar o trabalho.
>   (3) Terminar o trabalho levou ao João três horas.

A primeira não me suscita dúvidas.

Mas a segunda não tenho a certeza. Carlos Rocha, no Ciberdúvidas, [admite](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/levar-e-demorar-na-expressao-do-tempo/28556) «levou 55 anos para que a situação retomasse sua normalidade», mas parece restringir este uso a casos em que «o tempo que transcorre não é referido a nenhuma entidade» e diz ser um uso impessoal, como «haver» (algo que de que duvido, tal como 3, 2 parece-me parafraseável por *Isso levou ao João três horas*, e não *Levou ao João três horas para isso*, mas pode ser que esteja simplesmente a confundir com 3).

Já a terceira lembra-me «levar» no sentido normal de «tirar».

---

Consultei o Dicionário de Verbos e Regimes de Francisco Fernandes (45.ª ed.), e este apenas menciona construções como (3):

> *Transitivo-relativo*: ... Tomar: “Que é a filologia? Responder a esta pergunta....LEVAR-me-IA muito tempo.”

Também tem uma construção não diretamente coberta na pergunta:

> *Transitivo*: ... Gastar, consumir; tomar (falando do tempo): “Hoje tenho ainda trabalhos de escrita e estudo que me devem LEVAR a noite toda.”

Comment: Acho que se encaixa a tag Brasil aqui, que eu conheça em Portugal não se usa "levar" no sentido de "demorar".

Comment: @JorgeB. Usa-se bastante em Portugal. Exemplos abundam no CETEMPúblico. É o significado 26 do Aulete e parece ser o significado 10 do Priberam (gastar). As abonações do Aulete são na linha de (1) e a se 10. corresponder a este significado, O Pirberam também estará na linha de (1) (O João gastou três horas...).

Comment: Suponho que não estejas interessado numa abordagem por inferência? Parece-me que procuras uma resposta mais académica.

Comment: @ANeves Inferência? Referes-te a abonações?

Comment: Refiro-me a uma abordagem por dedução («A e B, portanto C.»), por oposição a uma resposta mais tecnicista.

Comment: @ANeves Desde que a A e B sejam verdadeiros, C se siga de facto e C esteja relacionado com a pergunta...

Comment: A (2) me soa muito estranha. Eu diria "Levou três horas **para o João terminar** o trabalho. A (3) também soa estranha, e nem consigo pensar numa alternativa.

Comment: A (3) não me aparenta semanticamente incorreta, 'levar' como verbo t.d. iria se adequar à frase caso não tivesse o 'ao João'; talvez trocar por "para o João" seja mais prudente. Na (2) eu não saberia classificar sintaticamente, porém expressa bem o significado intentado.

Answer (score -1):

A segunda e terceira frase estão incorreta, pois o verbo levar é transitivo direto quando no sentido de passagem do tempo. Assim, não deve haver preposição após o verbo.

Incorreto: *"Levou ao João três horas a/para terminar o trabalho."*

Correto: *"Levou João três horas para terminar o trabalho."*

É importante ressaltar que o uso da ordem inversa nessa frase, ainda que tecnicamente correto, fica bastante esquisito aos ouvidos. Muito melhor seria:
"João levou três horas para terminar o trabalho".

A terceira frase também está incorreta, uma vez que o verbo "terminar", no sentido de transcorrer do tempo, é transitivo indireto, necessitando da preposição "para" antes do objeto "terminar". A frase também está duplamente errada, já que "levar", por ser um verbo transitivo direto, não leva a preposição+artigo "ao", conforme dito na frase 1. Assim, temos:

Incorreto:  *Terminar o trabalho levou ao João três horas.*
Correto: *Para terminar o trabalho levou João três horas.*

O uso da ordem inversa aqui é incomum (soa um pouco esquisito), ainda que tecnicamente correto. Melhor seria:
Correto e com melhor sonoridade: *"João levou três horas para terminar o trabalho."*

O uso da ordem invertida nesses casos geralmente é restrito a textos escritos, poéticos, rimas, músicas, ou outras situações em que a inversão da ordem normal (sujeito-verbo-objeto) pode trazer benefícios estruturais ou de sonoridade.

Alguns significados do verbo levar:

Levar, transitivo indireto = transportar.
Exemplo: *Levei a maçã à professora.*

Levar, transitivo direto = demorar.
Exemplo: *João levou três horas para chegar.*

Levar, transitivo direto = sofrer uma agressão.
Exemplo: *Eu levei um tapa. Eu levei um soco.*

Comment: É possível adicionar “a” ligado ao objeto direto para explicitar o objeto direto: https://mundoeducacao.uol.com.br/gramatica/objeto-direto-preposicionado.htm#:~:text=O%20objeto%20direto%20%C3%A9%20o,algumas%20vezes%2C%20pode%20aparecer%20preposicionado.&text=a)%20Acompanhado%20de%20verbos%20que%20exprimem%20sentimentos.